# Quand doit-on prononcer ou ne pas prononcer la dernière lettre d'un mot ?

Tags: prononciation

Je donne bénévolement des cours de Français à des enfants, et ils me posent souvent la question quant à la dernière lettre d'un mot: pourquoi doit-on des fois les prononcer, des fois non?

J'essaye à chaque fois de sortir une règle, mais immédiatement ils trouvent plusieurs mots courants qui font exception à cette règle. Je pense qu'il doit y avoir une règle relativement simple, mais je n'arrive pas à la trouver.

Exemples:

- "art", "et", alors que "net"
- temps
- vent
- vieux
- "je bus", alors que "un bus"
- "marcher", alors que "fer"
- "marcher", alors que "haïr", "flair"

Quelqu'un aurait-il une règle simple quant à ce problème?

Comment: Je suis tenté de répondre *non*, sauf pour les liaisons où il y a des règles complexes. Pour ce dernier point voir http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_%28French%29.

Comment: Est ce qu'il s'agit uniquement de noms communs ou de noms propres ? Dans ce dernier cas, impossible d'avoir une règle : ça dépend de la prononciation régionale...

Comment: Nom communs, noms communs; je rajoute des exemples de suite

Comment: alors pourquoi on lit nord nor et sud sud? Merci j aimerais vraiment savoir !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On ne prononce pas:

1. Les consonnes **D P S T X Z G**. En italien, on dit « DePoSiTo XZG », par exemple. Quand on a des voyelles ou un **h**, on prononce la liaison. « Les enfants » → /le.z‿ɑ̃.fɑ̃/

   Je voudrais écrire une liste d'exemples, mais je ne sais pas quoi choisir.
2. La voyelle **E**. Les autres sont prononcés. *« La porte et le piano. »*

Il y a des exceptions (par exemple, *métis*), mais ce sont des règles qui peuvent t'aider. Tu peux voir [cette page](http://it.wikibooks.org/wiki/Francese/Pronuncia#Ultime_lettere_delle_parole) sur Wikibooks pour plus d'information. C'est en italien, il n y a rien dans la page française.

Comment: j'aime beaucoup le "DePoSiTo XZG", qui sera facile à retenir pour mes élèves, merci :) Je rajouterai le "er" qui ne se prononce pas pour les verbes du premier groupe, et ça m'a l'air d'être la solution qui laisse le moins d'exceptions

Comment: :) De rien! :) "deposito" veut dire quelque chose come "magasin", donc si tu écris "DePoSiTo", tu sais quelles sont les consonants, et "XZG" peut être le nom de ce magasin. :)

Comment: @Evpok: Merci! J'ai ajouté « et » à l'autre exemple aussi. :)

Answer (score 4):

Je donne une règle "simple" à mes élèves : les consonnes finales NE SE PRONONCENT PAS sauf F L R M N C (lettres qu'on trouve dans le mot "filarmónica").

Dans le cas de la consonne "R" on ne prononce pasles mots qui finissent par -ER (sauf les monosyllabes ...)

En tout cas il y a beaucoup d'exceptions : mots d'origine étrangère, pour éviter la cacophonie ...

Answer (score 1):

Pour **autobus**, voici ce que dit le dictionnaire de l’Académie (9ème édition) :

> XXème siècle. Composé d' auto II et de l’élément suffixal -bus, issu
>   de la terminaison d’omnibus.

et à l'entrée **omnibus** :

> XIXème siècle. Mot latin, proprement « pour tous », datif de omnes, « tous ».

En latin on prononce le **s** final.

Quant à présumer qu'il y a là une règle générale, je ne saurais l’affirmer. Mais j’ai tendance à penser qu’on ne prononce généralement pas la ou les consonnes finales sauf si le mot vient d’une langue où on les prononce.

**Mise à jour** :

Je pense qu'on ne doit pas, d'une manière générale pour les *mots de plus d'une syllabe*, prononcer la dernière lettre d'un mot sauf :

1. les mots terminés par une de ces voyelles : a, i, o, u, y
2. les mots terminés par les consonnes : f, l ,r; ex.: relief, chacal, radar. Sauf les verbes du premier groupe à l'infinitif.
3. les mots d'origine étrangère.

Pour les mots d'une seule syllabe, c'est l'anarchie complète

Comment: "Banal"? "autocar"? "Flair", "haïr", "or", alors que "marcher"? "et", alors que "net"? J'ai aussi l'impression que la règle est du genre "en général elle ne se prononcent pas", mais je finis toujours par rajouter "sauf telle et telle consonne... enfin sauf si elles sont précédés de telle ou telle voyelle... enfin sauf si..."

Comment: @Mikalichov: Effectivement, on trouve toujours des exceptions d'exceptions ... Cependant, `banal` vient du latin médiéval `bannalis`, `autocar` vient de l'anglais, `haïr` est un infinitif (2ème groupe: on prononce toujours le `ir` final [ à moins que j'en oublie certains])

Answer (score 1):

Je n'ai malheureusement pas de réponse précise, juste une piste partielle.

J'avais lu quelque part, mais impossible de retrouver la référence, qu'il y avait quelque chose au sujet du féminin et du masculin, de l'oral et de l'écrit. À l'écrit, on marque une préférence grammaticale pour le masculin, tandis qu'à l'oral on préfère le féminin.

Ainsi, *petit* et *petite*.

On écrit *Le panier et la chaise sont petits* : sur l'accord grammatical, on préfère le masculin.

Mais à l'oral,  le *t* final manque pour le masculin (on dit *peti*), alors qu'il est dit au féminin (on dit *petite*); le masculin semble être une forme écornée du mot, et l'on réserve la forme complète seulement au féminin, qui serait donc privilégié.

Si cette idée est confirmée, il faut donc regarder non pas seulement les règles grammaticales, mais aussi les règles d'oral, dans leur logique propre ; à l'oral, il y aurait une logique vers le féminin, que l'on ne retrouve pas à l'écrit.

Mais même si c'est confirmé, ça ne couvre qu'une petite partie du problème, désolé.

---

Après quelques recherches, on trouve des choses en ce sens dans **Approches de la Langue Parlee**, de *Claire Blanche-Benveniste* ; le bouqin semble en [lecture libre sur google book](http://books.google.fr/books?id=b6Il8cGFkdMC), mais je ne sais pas du tout ce qu'il vaut, c'est juste qu'il exprime des choses qui ressemblent à ce que j'avais lues. Le passage intéressant (me semble-t-il) se trouve à la page 143 :

> L'effet unificateur de l'orthographe masque certaines différences
>   entre les types de morphèmes utilisés par écrit et par oral.

C'est à dire, me semble-t-il, que l'orthographe et la grammaire sont trompeurs pour l'analyse de l'oral. Il faut se baser prioritairement sur ce qui est prononcé, et des relations entre prononcés.

> Par exemple, là où il y a, par écrit, un suffixe additif pour marquer
>   le féminin, gris / gris-e, plat / plat-e, grand / grand-e, **il n'y a
>   oralement aucun suffixe mais un changement dans la longueur du
>   radical**.

Et ainsi de suite, si ça vous intéresse, lisez le reste.

Je ne suis pas sûr que tout cela réponde à la question initiale, en tous les cas cela exprime mieux ce que je voulais dire.

Comment: Le masculin est en général la forme non-fléchie, ce qui n'a pas de rapport avec un quelconque écornage, on ajoute une flexion au féminin plus qu'on retire la fin du mot au masculin. Je ne vois en tout cas pas pourquoi ça signifierait qu'on privilégie le féminin à l'oral ou le masculin à l'écrit.

Comment: Justement, cette étude considérait que la forme féminine était la forme complète à l'oral, et qu'on retirait, qu'on diminuait le terme à la forme masculine. Le féminin, comme forme fléchie du masculin, ça, c'est pour l'écrit. On peut justifier cette idée pour l'oral par le fait que, si à l'écrit le féminin est toujours "e", à l'oral le féminin s'entend souvent de façon variable, de façon propre au terme : "petiT", "granD", "lonGU"... mais je m'excuse d'avoir perdu la référence, aussi je disais ça surtout pour savoir si quelqu'un avait vu ça aussi.

Comment: C'est beaucoup plus simple et clair de considérer que la forme minimale est la forme de base et qu'une forme plus complexe est fléchie. Je ne vois vraiment pas pourquoi on ferais l'inverse à l'oral, ni pourquoi on supposerait que l'écrit et l'oral ne dépendent pas du même système morphologique. J'ai du mal à croire que ça puisse aboutir à quelque chose, mais si tu retrouve de la doc, je suis preneur.

Comment: Mais je ne sais pas pourquoi ça se fait comme ça, ça se constate, tout simplement ! À l'oral, pour le mot "long" par exemple, on dit "lon" (pas de son "g") au masculin, on dit "long" ("g") au féminin. Et il est difficile de dire que "lon" est une forme de base, puisque l'ajout d'un "g" n'est pas une forme régulière (alors que l'ajout d'un e à l'écrit l'est). Le son "g" ne peut être considéré comme une flexion. Bon, je vais refaire des recherches de doc et dès que je trouve je dis.

Comment: Ce n'est pas une question de régularité : c'est beaucoup plus simple si une flexion est un ajout plutôt qu'un retrait.

Comment: J'ai fait un edit de ma réponse qui précise un petit peu par rapport à une référence que j'ai pu trouver, et que vous pourrez regarder vous aussi. Cordialement.

Answer (score -2):

Tou cela est très compliqué, puisqu'il existe bien des règles, notamment celle des noms commun finissant par "s" au singulier: la règle dit qu'il faut prononcer le "s" au singulier et ne pas le prononcer au pluriel. L'exemple bien connu  est: [ un os ("oss"), des os ("ô") ]. Une faute courante aujourd'hui consiste à prononcer le "s" de "moeurs" alors qu'il s'agit d'un pluriel et qu'on ne doit donc pas le prononcer. De même, on devrait omettre de prononcer le "s" au pluriel du mot "ours". Selon la règle, on devrait dire des "autobu(s)", bien que ce mot, né après la règle, semble s'en être affranchi dès l'origine...